# A function that displays a search from another function; dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have a list and two functions. One is a search function and the other displays what was searched.

```
list = {
1 : ("1200", "Walnut St", 919822),
2: ("1300", "Adam Dr", 919823),
3: ("1200", "Rodeo Dr", 919823),
}

def search(word_searched):
#prints list of key that contains word_searched

def show(list_ID):
#do stuff
```

My question is if I search for "1200" how do I get it to return this:

```
1
3
```

Comment: If you find yourself doing this a lot, consider building a reverse dictionary, with "1200" as a key and [1,3] as its value, and updating both at the same time when you add a new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> dic = {                                      
1 : ("1200", "Walnut St", 919822),
2: ("1300", "Adam Dr", 919823),
3: ("1200", "Rodeo Dr", 919823),
}
>>> [k for k,v in dic.iteritems() if "1200" in v]
[1, 3]
```

For py3.x:

```
>>> [k for k,v in dic.items() if "1200" in v]
[1, 3]
```

If you're doing this multiple times then it's better to create a new dict for improved performance:

```
>>> d = {}
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    d.setdefault(v[0],[]).append(k)

>>> d
{'1300': [2], '1200': [1, 3]}

>>> d["1200"]
[1, 3]
>>> d["1300"]
[2]
```

Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Is there a way to just iterate over the dictionary rather than using a list comprehension?

Comment: @MarkJasonIledanHunt I am iterating over the dict only, Fetching `key,val` from `dic.items()` in each iteration.